# Browser reload doesn't reload current Angular view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The problem I'm having is that after a user logs-in or signs-up they are redirected to the games view, this happens within the createUser function or after a successful authentication; in either case the redirect is handled with `$state.go('games')`.

This all works fine, however, if the user navigates away from the games view to any other state like **createGame** or **dashBoard** and then refreshes the browser in one of those views they are always redirected back to the games view. When I remove the `$state.go('games')` this doesn't happen, and reload will only reload the current view (like it should).

I have tried changing parameters on `$state.go` and tried using `$state.transitionTo()`, but nothing changes this behavior.

Is this just normal behavior for `$state.go`? If not, am I using it wrong, and are there other ways to redirect? What can I do to stop this behavior?

```
var game = angular.module('game', ['ui.router','firebase']);

game.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider,$locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $stateProvider.state('signUp', {
   url: '/signUp',
   templateUrl: '/templates/signUp.html'
  });

  $stateProvider.state('games', {
     url: '/games',
     templateUrl: '/templates/games.html',
     controller: 'games.controller'
    });

  $stateProvider.state('login', {
   url: '/login',
   templateUrl: '/templates/login.html'
  });

  $stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
   url: '/dashboard',
   templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard.html',
   controller: 'dashboard.controller'
  });

  $stateProvider.state('createGame', {
   url: '/createGame',
   templateUrl: '/templates/createGame.html',
   controller: 'createGame.controller'
  });

}]);


// Root reference to database
game.factory("Fire", function($firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://money-game.firebaseIO.com/");
    return ref;
});

// Gives access to auth methods
game.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth", "Fire",
  function($firebaseAuth, fire) {
    return $firebaseAuth(fire);
  }
]);



game.controller('app.controller', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'Auth', 'Fire', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, auth, fire) {
  $scope.user = {
    email : '',
    password : ''
  };

  $scope.signUp = function() {
    auth.$createUser($scope.user)
    .then(function(userData) {
      // After successful signup save a user record to users under their auth ID
      fire.child('users').child(userData.uid).set({
        name : $scope.user.name,
        email : $scope.user.email,
        joined : Date.now()
      });
      $state.go('games');
      console.log("User " + userData.uid + " created successfully!");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error: ", error);
    });
  };
  $scope.login = function() {
    auth.$authWithPassword($scope.user).catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
    });
  };
  $scope.logout = function() {
    auth.$unauth();
    window.location = '/';
  };

  auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
    if (authData) {
      $scope.activeUser = authData;

      // After user logs in find user record by auth id
      fire.child('users').child(authData.uid).on('value', function(snapshot) {
        // Checks if user exsists
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          // sets scope user to the user data
          $scope.user = snapshot.val();
          // sets scope user id to the auth id
          $scope.user.id = snapshot.key();
        }
      });
      console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
      $state.go('games');

    } else {
      $scope.activeUser = false;
      // $scope.user = '';
    }
  });
}]);


game.controller('games.controller', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'Auth', '$firebaseArray','Fire', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, auth, $firebaseArray, fire) {

  $scope.games = $firebaseArray(fire.child('games'));
  $scope.view = 'listView';

  $scope.setCurrentGame = function(game) {
    $scope.currentGame = game;
  };

  $scope.addPlayer = function(game) {
    console.log(game.$id);
    var ref = fire.child('players').child(game.$id);
    ref.push({
      id : $scope.user.id,
      name : $scope.user.name,
      email : $scope.user.email
    })
  };

  // swap DOM structure in games state
  $scope.changeView = function(view){
    $scope.view = view;
  }
}]);

game.controller('createGame.controller', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'Auth', '$firebaseArray','Fire', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, auth, $firebaseArray, fire) {

  $scope.games = $firebaseArray(fire.child('games'));

  $scope.createGame = function() {
    if ($scope.format == 'Match Play') {
      $scope.skinAmount = 'DOES NOT APPLY';
      $scope.birdieAmount = 'DOES NOT APPLY';
    }
    $scope.games.$add({
      name: $scope.gameName,
      host: $scope.user.name,
      date: $scope.gameDate,
      location: {
        course: $scope.courseName,
        address: $scope.courseAddress
      },
      rules: {
        amount: $scope.gameAmount,
        perSkin: $scope.skinAmount,
        perBirdie: $scope.birdieAmount,
        format: $scope.format,
        holes : $scope.holes,
        time: $scope.time
      }
    })
    // $state.go('games');
  };
}]);
```

Comment: `$state.go()` means go to the state you are specifying. So it sounds like its working fine. Are you saying if you uncomment the `$state.go` in the controller then it will go to games? If so, thats correct.

Comment: Its commented out because I was working on it, sorry. Redirecting to games works fine, but any time after that the browser is reloaded/refreshed it will always go back to the games view, instead of reloading the current view. Example: if I'm here http://localhost:3010/createGame, and click the reload button, I'm taken here http://localhost:3010/games. This is only the case when I redirect using $state.go(), if I remove it, clicking the reload button on the browser will reload whatever view I'm on without always going back to the games view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It's not about $state.go

It's actually about when you call it, $state.go does one simple thing : trigger a change in the routing state off your application. You just happen to do it everytime your application authenticates your user against your $firebaseAuth service, in the $onAuth handler.

## A single page app is an app

When you refresh the page in the browser, the entire app reloads, starts again, boostraps everything to display your app. This startup process includes re-authenticating your user (I didn't quite see where it is done in your code, but it *has* to be done), thus triggering the $onAuth handler again… and ultimately execute $state.go('games') again.

## Put your $state.go invocation elsewhere

You don't actually *mean* to do it every time your app authenticates the user, you rather want to do it when your user performs a successful login or sign-up action.
$authWithPassword returns a promise, you could do the state change in a success callback when the promise is resolved.

Hope that helps !

Comment: The trials and tribulations of learning how to code...lol. This worked perfect! Thank you.